# How do i restart a service which is in a remote server using Jenkins pipeline steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Here is my issue I have a service(nhasi. service) running on a remote Linux server,, I have created my Jenkins pipeline which copies my jar file to the remote server. So I want when copying file is done, the nhasi.service has to be restarted. I have tried the command below

```
sh 'sudo systemctl restart nhasi.service'
```

but I am getting the following error`systemctl: command not found`

My Jenkins server is running on a windows server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you [@ycr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2627018/ycr), your answer helped to find the final solution , i implemented as below

```
stage("Restarting Service") {
    
steps{
    script{
    def remote = [:]
    remote.name = 'test'
    remote.host = 'test.domain.com'
    remote.user = 'root'
    remote.password = 'password'
    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "systemctl restart nhasi.service"
    }
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sh 'sudo systemctl restart nhasi.service'` will execute the command in the Jenkins machine itself. So you have SSH into the remote machine and execute the commans. You can use something like [SSH Step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/) for this.

```
def remote = [:]
    remote.name = 'test'
    remote.host = 'test.domain.com'
    remote.user = 'root'
    remote.password = 'password'
    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
    stage('Remote SSH') {
      sshCommand remote: remote, command: "systemctl restart nhasi.service"
    }
```

Another option is to add the remote server as a Jenkins agent and execute the command on the remote Agent.